# Распознание регистра в php

Tags: php

В сети нашел синонимайзер на php, но он не учитывает регистр букв. Подскажите как заставить его распознавать автоматически регистр букв.

В данном случае слово "Мобильный" заменяется низким регистром, а желательно с большим регистром так как заменяемое слово идет с большим регистром.

```
function _strtr($str,$repl_array){
  $keys = array_map(function($key){
                  return '#'.$key.'#ui';
               },array_keys($repl_array));
  $values = array_values($repl_array);
  $values = array_map(function($value){
                  $variants = explode('|', $value);
                  return $variants[rand(0, count($variants) - 1)];
               },array_values($repl_array));
  return preg_replace($keys,$values,$str);
}
echo _strtr('Мобильный телефон Samsung обменяю на новый iphone',
  array(
     'мобильный'=>'сотовый'
   )
);
```

Comment: Вообще не понятно, что вы хотите. Что значит `заставить его распознавать автоматически регистр букв.` ? Либо регистронезависимо либо с учетом регистра.

Comment: С учетом регистра.

Comment: Уберите флаг `i` и будет с учетом регистра.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
return '#'.$key.'#ui';
```

Заменить на:

```
return '#'.$key.'#u';
```

И отправлять такой массив:

```
echo _strtr('Мобильный телефон Samsung обменяю на новый iphone', array(
    'мобильный' => 'сотовый',
    'Мобильный' => 'Сотовый',
        )
);
```

Все остальное будут уже костыли